# HTML5 Canvas for falling word game

Tags: api, html, mobile

I want to develop a game which will have following content
1. User will log in
2. User will be provided by alphabets of a word falling from sky, and he would be required to complete the word before they hit the bottom level. 
3. The words would be pulled up from a database. 
4. The reward points gathered by user on completion of task, would be converted to a corresponding "Mobile recharge topup" and would be sent to users mobile.

I was planning to do this in a html5 using Canvas element. Could you let me know, if this is possible.

I have studied 5 mobile recharge api service, but none of them are satisfactory so far. Any direction in there?

To give you an idea of my expertise with this, I am a totally new user of web programming. I have been a systems programmer before, and need to develop this for assisting in a research project related to studying economic incentives of attracting low income workers to spend time on web, if enough incentive is provided.

I sincerely appreciate your time and help.

Thank you,
Mrunal

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please read through the [faq](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) if you haven't.

Comment: My question has got misformatted and misaligned. Apologies for the same. I read the FAQ, could you please point out specifically, what are the areas of improvements in my question other than alignment. thanks.

Answer (score -2):

This is what I have found.
It is a half baked script ...

http://www.javascriptsource.com/games/falling-by-tim-withers-120409100502.html